# prevent scrolling or fixed position but inside body?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
position:relative;
}

.parent{
position:fixed;
z-index:20;
right:14px;
top:0;
width:140px;
height:100vh;
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</div>
```

This is exactly what I need as layout. Except - on a large monitor (larger than 1366px - that is my body width) `parent` goes far right, outside of the body.

I tried with `position:absolute` but in that case `parent` is scrolling with body.

How can I get fixed position (just prevent scrolling), but inside body?

Comment: I can't seem to see the problem you're describing (It looks the same all all widths) Does it occur in your snippet for you? If so, could you add a screenshot of the problem? and perhaps which browser you're using to cause the issue?

Comment: Your demo works as expected and the question is unclear.

Comment: @DBS make your body 960px width and you'll see.

Comment: @Stickers, demo works, but as I said - `on a larger monitor...`

Comment: How it should be? The body tag is always 100% width by default.

Comment: @Stickers my body 1366px, thats a template. On a monitor with 1920px  - there is the problem.

Comment: It looks fine at 960px to me, as well as every other width (I tested from 350px to 2500px) Are you testing on your snippet or the original code? Unless you're in an old browser, the snippet doesn't look like it could ever cause issues like you're describing.

Comment: Is it responsive, and is the layout centered?

Comment: @Stickers, yes layout is responsive and body is always on center and max 1366px.

Comment: You should use `position:absolute` because `position:fixed` is always relative to the viewport not the parent.

Have you tried `overflow-y:hidden` on body along with `position:absolute`?

Comment: @DBS that's impssible. If body is 960px (for example) and monitor is 1920px (for example) `parent` is far outside of the body.

Comment: @Kesavamoorthi, you probably mean `overflow-x`. Tried and doesn't help.

Comment: Then, you probably need to drop fixed position or use javascripts.

Comment: There is nothing in your snippet that would limit the size of the `body`. We can only test the snippet you've provided, as I said before, have you managed to actually reproduce the issue in the snippet? (NOT your original code, click the "Run code snippet" then "Full Page") If we can't see the problem the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @DBS, in snippet generator I tried to change body width but it is not possible.

Comment: Do you want to prevent vertical scrolling or horizontal one?

Comment: @Kesavamoorthi, `parent` is vertically inside `body`. Problem is because horizontally it is outside of body if body is smaller then monitor and if position is `fixed`. On a position `absolute` parent is inside body but it is scrolled togethar with body. So I need it inside body but not scrollable with body scrolling. Ugh!.

Comment: The closest you can get with only css - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOXqvB

Comment: @Stickers, thanks, I see your point, but can't believe that there is no any more natural way.